# Difference between strlen(str.c_str()) and str.length() for std::string

Tags: c++, string, stl

As an implicit understanding, I always thought that every implementation of `std::string` necessarily must satisfy `strlen(str.c_str()) == str.length()` for every string `str`.

What does the C++ standard say about this? (Does it?)

*Background:* At least the implementations shipped with Visual C++ and gcc do not have this property.  Consider this example (see [here for a live example](http://ideone.com/kWM3VV)):

```
// Output:
// string says its length is: 13
// strlen says: 5
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>

int main() {
  std::string str = "Hello, world!";
  str[5] = 0;
  std::cout << "string says its length is: " << str.length() << std::endl;
  std::cout << "strlen says: " << strlen(str.c_str()) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Of course, the writing operation without `str` noticing is causing "the problem". But that's not my question. I want to know what the standard has to say about this behavior.

Comment: `std::string` supports NUL characters. C strings do not.

Comment: @chris: Do you have a reference to the standard?

Comment: I think Lightness has it. I didn't see anything, but the only reason you would expect an explicit statement for a string that knows its length is to contrast it with C strings. Do note that you can certainly embed NULs in `char*`, though. For example, `BSTR` contains a length prefix, followed by data, followed by two NULs (the characters in there are `wchar_t`, but the same idea applies).

Comment: _"I always thought that every implementation of std::string necessarily must satisfy strlen(str.c_str()) == str.length() for every string str."_ Why did you think this, and why would it be necessary? Addressing the root of your confusion may be more constructive.

Comment: A std::string remembers its length, so `std::string::length()` does not call `strlen()` every time,  it just returns the stored length. Inserting a nul byte into the string does not change the stored length.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your understanding is incorrect. Sort of.

`std::string` may contain `char`s with the value `'\0'`; when you extract a C-string, you have no way of knowing how long it is other than to scan for `\0`s, which by necessity cannot account for "binary data".

This is a limitation of `strlen`, and one that `std::string` "fixes" by actually remembering this metadata as a count of `char`s that it knows are encapsulated.

The standard doesn't really need to "say" anything about it, except that `std::string::length` gives you the string length, no matter what the value of the `char`s you inserted into the string, and that is it not prohibited to insert a `'\0'`. By contrast, `strlen` is defined to tell you how many `char`s exist up to the next `\0`, which is a fundamentally different definition.

There is no explicit wording about this, because there does not need to be. If there were an exception to the very simple rules ("there is a string; it has `char`s; it can tell you how many `char`s it has") then *that* would be stated explicitly… and it's not.

Comment: @Xlea: It is not and does not need to be specified explicitly. Strings accept `char`s (with no mention of a restriction on their value), and the string class can tell you the number of `char`s in the string. There is no wording to state "except that this is broken in the same way as `strlen` is, despite the fact that the entire purpose of this class is to improve upon the horrible C-string semantics". I can't prove a negative!

Comment: What is ambiguous about "working consistently"? There are strings. Strings contain `char`s. Strings can tell you how many `char`s are in them. This function will always work. That's it....

Comment: @Xlea: AFAIK there's no explicit statement in the standard that "`str.length()` might give a different answer from `std::strlen(str.c_str())`". But there doesn't have to be, since you can work it out from the definitions of the functions. `string::length` is defined to return the number of characters in the string, whereas `strlen` is defined to return the number of characters up to the first 0 character.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit:  `std::string` semantics (it's the most sensible I can imagine) is "vector of chars", then. I perfectly agree that it is the right design for an `std::string` when designing from scratch. Yet, there is backward compatibility and with this semantics at hand you have to be much more careful when porting old code to `std::string`. Btw, I can also define "consistent behavior" in C-style strings (i.e., with a special terminating symbol, e.g., given in a trait). So "working consistently" refers right back to the definition of what a "string" is and thus explains nothing.

Comment: @Xlea: "Working consistently" means "functioning per the requirements of the language, for all valid inputs, always". Period.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Precisely. My question was exactly what are those "requirements of the language", question mark. But, let's end the discussion here. I got the point and that it's (only) implicit in the standard.

Comment: @Xlea, nonsense, it's not implicit. The standard clearly states that `length()` and `size()` are the number of elements held by the string, not the number of leftmost non-zero elements. See NathanOliver's answer. As for backward compatibility, `std::string` is not supposed to be backward compatible with `char*`, it's supposed to have other semantics such as storing its length. If you want a C string then call `c_str()` and use the C string functions.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: I disagree. You assume an *implicit* understanding of what it means for a string to "hold" an element. Why should the C-answer be incorrect? (It may seem pedantic, but a precise, explicit semantic definition is exactly the point of my question.) But let's leave it at that.

Comment: @Xlea, no, the standard is very explicit in several places. See the `basic_string(const char_type* s, size_type n, const Allocator&)` constructor which sets the string length to `n` not `strlen(s)`, see the fact that `length()` is required to be constant time (not linear like `strlen`), see the fact that `resize(size_type)` increases the size **by adding `'\0'` characters to the string!** Obviously you can't change the result of `strlen()` by appending zero bytes to the end! Did you even try to find the answer in the standard before requesting that others provide references for you?

Comment: That's more convincing. Btw, the discussion evolved from a first version of the post, just stating std::string::length 'works consistently' which eludes the answer. So, yeah, sorry for asking a _question_ on _stackoverflow_.

Comment: There was nothing wrong with the original wording (plus I think you meant "evades", not "eludes"); I only changed it because you (as the OP) failed to comprehend it!

Comment: Yes, I'm not a native speaker, thanks for pointing *that* out; I don't think to rub it in does not improve the emotions here, do you? Now, I think it unfair for Jonathan (or you at that) to downvote the question, just because you disagree with the comments. (Correct me if it wasn't either of you and, in that case, consider this as my apologies.) I would have understood downvoting the comment (is there such a thing?), but not downvoting the answer. I even accepted your (edited) answer, didn't I? What's more, I even upvoted it.

Comment: @Xlea: I'm not "rubbing it in", I'm kindly informing you for free so that you can improve in the future. You're welcome. And who is "downvoting the question just because we disagree with the comments"? No idea where you got that notion from. Sorry but I don't really understand what you're talking about.

Comment: Of course. I think it's quite a coincidence that the downvote is not 5min after Jonathan's emotionally quite charged answer. That's no proof so, naturally, mea culpa! Btw, is there a kind of "private chat feature" in stackoverflow, because I don't think this is still relevant for the question?

Comment: @Xlea: It's a million miles from proof. I didn't downvote the question and I doubt Jonathan did either. No need for "private chat" (though yes, there is such a thing) as the question is solved!

Answer (score 3):

Standard C function `std::strlen` calculates the length of a character array based on the presence of the terminating zero in the array.
On the other hand objects of class `std::string` may have embedded zeroes. Thus function strlen applied to c_str() can yields result that differs from the value returned by member function length.

Consider a simple example

```
std::string s( 10, '\0' );

std::cout << s.length() << std::endl;
std::cout << std::strlen( s.c_str() ) << std::endl;
```

In this case the first output statement will output 10 while the second output statement will output 0.

Moreover if you have a string like for example

```
std::string s( "Hello" );
```

and then call member function resize

```
s.resize( 10 );
```

then the function appends the original string with four values of type `char()` that is by zeroes. And member function `s.length()` returns 10.

Answer (score 1):

The standard has this to say about `length()` from string

> Returns: size().

And `size()` is defined as

> Returns: A count of the number of char-like objects currently in the string.

So as you can see you will get the number of char like objects in the string even if the char like objects value is `'\0'`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, because that's what 21.2 [strings.general] defines to refer to any character type stored in a `basic_string`. "This Clause describes components for manipulating sequences of any non-array POD (3.9) type. In this Clause such types are called _char-like types_, and objects of char-like types are called _char-like objects_ or
simply _characters_."

Comment: @JonathanWakely: Seems strange wording though? It could have said "`CharT` objects" instead. I acknowledge that it's well-defined in this clause, but why go to the trouble of introducing a new term? Oh well.

Comment: The quote was from the definition of basic_string 21.4.4 and maybe they are covering for he fact that it can also hold wide characters which are `char`-like and not `char`

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, in some contexts where it's used in Clause 21 there is no `_CharT` template parameter "in scope" for the wording.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, *In the rest of this
Clause, the type of the char-like objects held in a basic_string object is designated by charT.* - I guess it's just that `charT` is defined in terms of this, not the other way around.

Comment: Again, that's a matter of definition of the underlying semantics. What is "inside a string"? For example, C defines to be in the string all characters to the right of the start and strictly to the left of the first 0-character (assuming for simplicity that there's one). I guess the best hint is the absolute symmetry of all characters.

Comment: @Xlea: C doesn't really define string at all, which is the key here.